# CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv returns empty strings serializing generic List of custom objects

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm trying to parse a generic list of custom class to csv string using ServiceStack.Text.CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv().

All seems to work fine, but returns only empty lines for each instance of object in the list.

```
class ListEntry : IComparable<ListEntry>
{        
    public string SomeField1;
    public string SomeField2;
}

class CurrentList : List<TaskQueueEntry>
{
}

var testList = new CurrentList();
testList.Add(new ListEntry("pam","tam");
testList.Add(new ListEntry("qqq","aaa");

string csvQueueInit = CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv(testList)
```

Expected:

```
SomeField1,SomeField2
pam,tam
qqq,aaa
```

Actual:

```
"","
","","
","","
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **public properties**, e.g:

```
class ListEntry : IComparable<ListEntry>
{        
    public string SomeField1 { get; set; }
    public string SomeField2 { get; set; }
}
```

Or configure it to serialize **public fields** with:

```
JsConfig.Init(new Config {
    IncludePublicFields = true
});
```

Comment: "always use properties, not fields" (c)
Seems to start working, but now it splitting each and every symbol with a comma:
Like this: ",U,p,d,a,t,e, ,(,v,.,1,),",",f,i,l,e,n,a,m,e,"

Comment: @laooglee Your code doesn't compile, I've made updates so that the code compiles  with this [live example on Gistlyn](https://gistlyn.com/?gist=17142ed8796b025466460dfd67635b9d) which works as expected. If you have another issue ask a new question with stand-alone source code that compiles, preferably linking to a live example on Gistlyn which shows the issue.

Comment: ouch. double-serializing, this was the issue:
            `string csvQueueInit = CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv(testQueue);
            System.Console.WriteLine(CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv(csvQueueInit));`